# Mixing SystemC modules with Omnet++ modules

Tags: omnet++, systemc

I'm interested to mix SystemC  modules with Omnet++ modules.

According to the [Omnet++ manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:plugin-exts:scheduler), this feature is supported. However, I couldn't find any further documentation or examples.

Can anyone help me with this procedure? How to enable this feature? how to load and two future event lists in the simulation? any example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ does not contain the SystemC integration code. I suggest to get in touch with the developers to get your hand on it.